# Web Service, accessing in html page ? Getting error?

Tags: web-services

Web service, Accessing Service in html page i am getting error, this is my code.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
<title>Untitled Page</title>
<script type ="text/javascript"  language="JavaScript">
 function InitializeService()     
 {
    service.useService(http://www.freewebservicesx.com/GetGoldPrice.asmx?WSDL,
    "GetCurrentGoldPrice");

 }

 Function getgold()
 {
   var users="xxxxx";
   var pawd="xxx";
   service.GetCurrentGoldPrice.callService("GetCurrentGoldPrice",users,pawd);
 }

   function ShowResult()
   {
     alert(event.result.value);
   } 

 </script>

 </head>
  <body  onload="InitializeService()" id="service"  onresult="ShowResult()">
  <button onclick="getgold()">Get Age</button>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: These may come handy... `http://www.webreference.com/js/column97/2.html` and `http://www.webpronews.com/html-client-for-web-services-using-dhtml-behavior-2004-04` ... I am still in a confusion whether you should have used the 'behaviour' or not...

Comment: i am  getting java srcript error, "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected" ....... at <body  onload="InitializeService()" id="service"  onresult="ShowResult()">

Comment: when i tried this web service in asp.net it is working fine

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable the following property in your IE browser "Initialize and script ActiveX controls not marked as safe for scripting"

From Internet Explorer, go to Tools >> Internet Options>>Security tab, go to Custom level.
Enable "Initialize and script ActiveX controls not marked as safe for scripting" option and click OK.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried it with jsfiddle... Here it is http://jsfiddle.net/XNEhp/

Try changing the `Function getgold()` to `function getgold()`

And do the following changes..

From

```
function InitializeService()     
 {
    service.useService(http://www.freewebservicesx.com/GetGoldPrice.asmx?WSDL,
    "GetCurrentGoldPrice");

 }
```

To

```
 function InitializeService()     
 {
    service.useService('http://www.freewebservicesx.com/GetGoldPrice.asmx?WSDL',
    'GetCurrentGoldPrice');

 }
```

Let me know what happens now...

Hope it helps.

Comment: i am getting error: "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method"

Comment: This seems to have different problems with different browsers.. Try JSON instead... may be SOAP will help...